# eclipse, how to change method call without the addition of new brackets?

Tags: eclipse, format, formatting

Is it posible, with eclipse, to change the called method name using of auto completion (ctrl + space) but without creating a new brackets.  Otherwise I have double brackets:

```
person.hello()();
```

and must manually delete new brackets.

~thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the preference

```
Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Insert
```

form "*Completion inserts*" to "*Completion overwrites*". You can also toggle the settings while the content assist is active - thus if you do not want to change the global setting just hold down the `Ctrl` key while pressing `enter` on the new method on the provided method list which you opened with `Ctrl-Space`.

Answer (score -1):

Double-click on the method name, hit Ctrl+F, fill in "Replace with" field with new method name, hit "Replace/Find" to do it one by one or "Replace All".